# Mandatory to use Darwin or wowza or VLC to stream live video in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to know is it mandatory to use any of the streaming servers like Darwin,Wowza or VLC to stream an RTSP live stream video? I am receiving an RTSP link from my client and it tends to change everytime. I can successfully play it in the VLC player but on phone I cant see anything. I tried playing a sample link having .3gp extension and it worked fine. But my links dont have an extension. They look like this rtsp://122.166.229.151:1950/1346a0cf0ef7c2. Please help me.If its compulsory to use an extension or a server, I will continue working in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

A streaming server (as you describe) isn't strictly necessary - as long as you can pull RTSP from whatever your source is, you should be able to see it. Most IP cameras have onboard RTSP servers (although I wouldn't put too many connections on it). If you can see it in VLC, the phone should be able to consume it as well, given that the codec used to encode is one supported by the android device (in most cases, if you're doing H.264 Baseline 3.0 with AAC, you should be good to go).

A streaming server like Wowza can make that stream available to a wider audience than pulling directly from the source device, but if you're not intending to broadcast to a wide audience, it's not required for streaming to Android devices.

Newer versions of Android (Gingerbread and later) are also able to consume Apple HTTP Live Streaming.